# Can a hard-set a status code in the web.config?

Tags: iis, web-config, http-status-code-404

I would like to return a 404 status code for every single request to a website. *I still want to deliver a page of content*, but I want the status code on every single request to be 404. (It's weird, I know, but there's a specific reason...)

I know I could do with this an HTTP Module or an OWIN pipeline, but I'd like to do it without writing or deploying code, if possible. However, this is a very weird situation, so I'm not sure if this is possible.

Can I set this from the web.config?

Comment: There is no such thing via web.config.

Answer (score 0):

As lex says, we couldn't return the right content page with 404 error status.

Here is a workaround, we could try to use custom error page to achieve your  requirement. If it should return 404 error, you could redirect the page to custom error page. But you should use the url rewrite to redirect all the pages to a not existed page.

Details about how to use custom error page in IIS, you could refer to this [article](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webtopics/2008/05/27/iis-7-0-http-error-pages/).

Details about how to use url rewrite, you could refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/creating-rewrite-rules-for-the-url-rewrite-module).